# Svelte document.readyState is behaving differently on Chrome and Firefox

Tags: javascript, svelte, sveltekit, svelte-component, onreadystatechange

I basically want a loading screen (a div element) to show for 2 seconds while the page is being loaded. I am using `document.readyState` for this and if it's completed loading everything then hide the loading screen else keep showing it.

The problem is, when I have this code, it works on Chrome but loads forever in Firefox (by loads forever I mean: *it didn't hided that loader div, however the document was ready actually and I got to know this when I removed that loading div through Inspect tab and saw that everything has loaded just fine*)

Now this code runs just fine in Chrome:

```
onMount(() => {
  const loader = <HTMLDivElement>document.getElementById('loader');
  if (document.readyState === 'complete') {
    setTimeout(() => {
      loader.style.visibility = 'hidden';
      console.log('loaded');
    }, 2000);
  }
});
```

But if I add `document.onreadystatechange` to it, now it works in Firefox but sadly now Chrome keeps loading forever as that `loader.style.visibility = 'hidden'` didn't fired:

```
document.onreadystatechange = () => {
  if (document.readyState === 'complete') {
    setTimeout(() => {
      loader.style.visibility = 'hidden';
      console.log('loaded');
    }, 2000);
  }
};
```

Why is this happening?

I tried console logging this:

```
document.onreadystatechange = () => {
  console.log("Hi");
};
```

This code doesn't even log anything on Chrome. But on Firefox it logs "Hi"

I guess it's a svelte thing as if you generally run this code inside a simple `index.html`'s `<script>` tag then it works on both Chrome and Firefox but with svelte and `onMount`, this doesn't even fires...

Comment: Is not that it doesn't fire, it simply fired before you could add the event listener.  In other words, by the time you add the event listener, the document has already loaded.  Where do you have this code?

Comment: @JoséRamírez it's inside a component and why is that different browsers are reacting different on this code. Like why is that chrome runs it and Firefox doesn't or vice versa

Comment: That is a question for the implementers of the behavior, not for me.  I can try to help if we focus on the code questions as opposed to those.  For example, it would be great to know where is your event subscription code to try to determine if it is the right place.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved my issue as I just used onMount() on the parent component.

It executes the loader function only when all of its child components are loaded which is what onMount() does. I should have already placed onMount on the root component...

However I still am not very sure as to why browsers acted so differently.